# A consequence of Jordan Curve Theorem?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have read a solution of an undergraduate complex analysis exercise (Jordan Curve Theorem known), where the following is considered obvious:

*Let $\gamma: [0,1]\to\mathbb C$ be a simple closed curve on the plane, 
and assume that $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$ are consecutive points of $\gamma$.  If the curves $\gamma_{1,3}$, which connects $A_1$ and $A_3$ and $\gamma_{2,4}$, which connects $A_2$ and $A_4$
lie in the interior of $\gamma$ (except their endpoints), then they intersect.*

$A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$ are consecutive points means that,  and $A_j=\gamma(t_j)$, where $0\le t_1<t_2<t_3<t_4<1$.

Is this really that obvious? Can it be dealt with only with the help of Jordan Curve Theorem?

Comment: Does your version of the Jordan Curve Theorem include the fact that the Jordan curve plus its interior is a disk?

Comment: Let's assume that too!